# log4j2: Programmatically set append=false

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have the following code, but I am really struggling with log4j documentation.
How do I set append=false to my file appender, so I get a new file for each run?

```
ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory
                .newConfigurationBuilder();

        builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ERROR);
        builder.setConfigurationName("IkodaLogBuilder");

        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder =    ........


        LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern",
                "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n");

        appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("file", "File").addAttribute("fileName", "./logs/ikoda.log")
                .add(layoutBuilder);
        builder.add(appenderBuilder);
```

Comment: You want to replace the previous file or just want to add a new file on each run?

Comment: yes, although really it is overwrite which  is the standard behaviour when append=true is set in log4j2.xml